# Scene graph for 2D engine

Tags: c++, 2d, scenegraph

For my experimental 2D engine, I want to include a scene graph implementation to, with good performance, **determine which objects have to be rendered** (are visible for the camera).

Unfortunately, I don't know much about the further details on how that would work. A scene graph, as far as I know, is at its core a tree-based structure which can be used to organize child-parent relationships better.

- How should one implement a 2D scene graph when aiming for the determination of what should be rendered in a single frame?

Comment: Perhaps read one of the many articles on the subject available on the web through a quick Google search.

Comment: I did not find anything related there, otherwise I wouldn't have asked here

Comment: When searching as @Tomalak suggests, an important keyword which may be helpful is **culling**.

Comment: I dont have a whole answer but finding which objects have to be rendered is easy in 2D : you just need the position and the bounding box of each object.

Comment: Check out wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSP_tree and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree

Comment: @JB Jansen: I have read those articles, yet I do not fully grasp how I would go for the implementation of the whole system

Comment: I think you need to study the articles _in depth_, and analyse your options _over a period of weeks_ or even months. You're not going to be able to look them up on Wikipedia then write your "whole system" within a few hours, and teaching you how to write a graphics engine is beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: So I can't expect an answer to my question of how to implement a scene graph in a 2D engine for culling, thanks bye

Comment: here's an example: [Qt: The Graphics View Framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/graphicsview.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a quad tree. To determine what to render in a frame you would discard any branches of the tree which are outside the view.